# I need an Input for Bar Index offset value

Tags: pine-script

I have a label that is plotted in the lower pane at a height of y = 105.  I need the label horizontally offset X number of bars to the left so it can be read (it has roughly 35 characters).  I need the offset value to be based on an input "Label_Offset".

Something has changed in the last 24 hrs in TradingView.  My code worked fine yesterday....
MANY Thanks in advance for any ideas!!
// ------------------

```
study(title = "Test", overlay=false)

Label_Offset =   input(title = "Label Offset", type = input.integer, defval = 25, step = 1)

if (barstate.islast) 
    labelText = Label_Text_Switch
    label.set_y(id = Label_Symb, y = 105)
    label.set_x(id = Label_Symb, x = bar_index[Label_Offset])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Pine runtime has changed. The `max_bars_back = 300` now in your `study()` statement will often need to be there from now on:

```
//@version=4
study(title = "Test", overlay=false, max_bars_back = 300)

Label_Offset =   input(title = "Label Offset", type = input.integer, defval = 25, step = 1)
Label_Text_Switch = "abcde"

if (barstate.islast)
    labelText = Label_Text_Switch
    var Label_Symb = label.new(bar_index, na, labelText)
    label.set_y(id = Label_Symb, y = 105)
    label.set_x(id = Label_Symb, x = bar_index[Label_Offset])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you LucF!!  I rec'd explanation also from TV support w/an explanation below.  I'll make the changes. 

"The error is caused by server-side changes related to performance improvements."